# Add all firmware to CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE?

Tags: linux, firmware, make

How can I add all the firmware present in `/lib/firmware` in the `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` parameter of the kernel `.config`?

I've already tried but when compiling the kernel it returns an error:

```
/bin/sh argument list too long
```

Kernel 5.10.67

Comment: Edit in the `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` & `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR` settings you tried and the exact error message.  I successfully built 5.17.4 with 11488 bytes worth of `amdgpu` firmware names in the `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` string.

Comment: It *does* however fail on my end with a `/bin/sh: Argument list too long` in [`drivers/base/firmware_loader/builtin/Makefile`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/base/firmware_loader/builtin/Makefile?h=v5.17.4) if I try to pass in 66083 bytes worth of filenames (every firmware filename from [`linux-firmware` tag `20220411`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/?h=20220411), minus some Broadcom firmware files with spaces in their names).

Comment: this is probably more suitable on [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 3):

Compiling and booting into an "intermediate" kernel with [`include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h:MAX_ARG_STRLEN`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h?h=v5.17.4#n15) set to `(PAGE_SIZE * 128)` let an "all firmware" build of [kernel 5.17.4](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/?h=v5.17.4) (plus linux-firmware tag [`20220411`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/?h=20220411)) complete for me.

Unfortunately [the stock Debian GRUB package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/grub-efi-amd64-bin) fails to actually *boot* the 210M (871M [uncompressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002789)) kernel and its 66M (212M uncompressed) IOUS ([Initrd Of Unusual Size](https://princessbride.fandom.com/wiki/R.O.U.S.)):

```
Loading Linux 5.17.4 ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: the initrd is too big.

Press any key to continue...
```

Thankfully bumping [`GRUB_LINUX_INITRD_MAX_ADDRESS`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/include/grub/i386/linux.h?h=grub-2.04#n24) up from `0x37FFFFFF` to `0xA7FFFFFF` (`0x77FFFFFF` was too small) lets the kernel + initrd boot on my machine.